# How to set acl permissions for specific sub-folders in many paths?

Tags: powershell, vbscript

Here is an example folder path: E:\Datastore\MarcStone Bids\7401-7450\7415 Building Renovation and Addition for Van Meter Community School District - Van Meter IA\Bid Documents

Note how the second to last directory is a job #/name. I have hundreds of these paths on a windows 2008 r2 server. Inside each one exists the exact same group of 10 folders which are created by a script. They inherit their parent permissions which is fine, EXCEPT for 3 of the 10 folders require a single additional acl permission. I want to add this additional permission through a script of some kind. I've looked at vbscript, but it seems wildcards in folder paths is a complication that is better handled by powershell, but I'm really not sure.

So, I would appreciate counsel on choosing a method to perform this action and then more importantly help to build a working script.

Thoughts??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thank you for posting a question, and we would like to assist you with how best to use this website. First, we are not a code writing service. We do write code, but we need you to take the first steps, and at least try to put something together. We are happy to help fix problems, but we need you to post what code you have, and then what error(s) you get, and where you get them, and we can help you fix those errors, or maybe show how you could have written it better to avoid them in the future.

Comment: I have no problem with that, and I'm certainly willing to do my work. I think my post makes it clear that I want to get a suggestion on which path to choose before I get into the code. I'm not a leech :~)

Comment: PowerShell can most definitely accomplish what you want. You would probably need to use Get-ChildItem, Get-ACL, and Set-ACL. Examples of setting ACLs can be found on this site if you search for `[powershell] acl`.

Answer (score 1):

Your simple answer lays in command line tools.

Type `icacls /?` and `for /?`

Using the dir command can give you a list of folders matching.

```
dir *partialfoldername* /ad /s /b
```

Putting it into a `for` loop.

```
for /f %A in ('dir *partialfoldername* /ad /s /b) do icacls %A /grant Administrator:F
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to experiment with that a bit and I'll post back later this week.